# JQuery background on hover function

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I am trying to make a menu where when you hover over an item and it changes the background image. Below is the JQuery I use to make that happen. Here is the problem. I have some specific styling on my stylesheet on the backgroundImage class that I want each menu item to have, such as, background-repeat:no-repeat. I don't want to have to apply that and the "default" picture to each menu item. So, I am going to have to edit the .mouseleave function so that when the mouse leaves, it will just go back to what I have in the stylesheet.

I tried to make as much sense as I could, but if you have questions, please just ask.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resume").hover(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(http://www.vhawley.com/wp-content/themes/vhawleycomtheme/css/style/images/menuResume.jpg)");
    });
    $(".resume").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(http://www.vhawley.com/wp-content/themes/vhawleycomtheme/css/style/images/menuDefault.jpg)");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: so what is happening with the current code?

Comment: When I hover over .resume, it changes the background, which is good, but then when I get off, it puts the default one back up, but it repeats it, which is defined not to do in my stylesheet.

Comment: Why are you doing this with jquery? Why can't you just use CSS `:hover` for swapping out an image?

Comment: I will try your solution, but if it works, please format it as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: Have you tried `.css("background-image",` instead of `.css("background",`?

Comment: Your solution worked Adeneo! Thanks! Make it an answer for credit though!

Comment: Did you try @j08691 solution, seems like a better approach to set the styles on the specific CSS properties, and not the shorthand `background`

Comment: @areneo already answered correctly, but now he is gone?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".resume").mouseenter(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(http://www.vhawley.com/wp-content/themes/vhawleycomtheme/css/style/images/menuResume.jpg)");
    });
    $(".resume").mouseleave(function () {
        $(".backgroundImage").css("background", "url(http://www.vhawley.com/wp-content/themes/vhawleycomtheme/css/style/images/menuDefault.jpg)");
    });
});
</script>
```